# After upgrade to Mountain Lion, Flex apps won't load on phone

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder, osx-mountain-lion

I've developed two air for android apps that are on the market using Adobe Air/ Flash Builder..

I just purchased a new mac laptop with Mountain Lion which is a big upgrade over my old machine.

The problem is, when I loaded my old project folders into Flash Builder 4.6 on my new machine, they compile fine with no errors.

When I hit run, it begins to export the app to the Android device like normal, it then tuns the device's screen black as if the app is starting... then crashes.

If I hit debug, it starts the connection countdown and never connects to the debugger. Then it turns black and crashes just as before.

It doesn't give me any errors at all. I can't run it in the simulator because it has extensions that break it.

Just as a test, I started a new project and ran that on my phone, and it worked perfectly. So it's only the old projects that won't work..

What's crazy is the same exact project folder, if i put it on a USB drive, put it on my old copmuter, or my friends Macbook with Lion, export it to android to the same Android device...it works!...

I've already tried the following:

- Re-installed flashbuilder 4.6, installed 4.7 and test with that
- Downloaded the projects off of svn, and directly from an external hardrive to see if it was svn error
- Deleted all hidden filed within the project folders that may have had machine specific information in them
- Started a new project under the same name, manually recreated all the folders and pasted each individual file into them
- Tested it on multiple devices to see if it was just my phone

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm at a total loss, because the projects work on my old computer with Snow Leopard, my friend's computer with Lion, but won't work on mine at all!

Comment: What happens if you build a proper release build? Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Generally when an application is tested locally, it will attempt to cross one or more sandboxes especially in the area of security. Loading local assets vs. networked URL assets, etc.

As far as I know it still holds true today, but if you place your development folder in the 'trusted' space, you're apps are allowed a lot more freedom. I'm assuming the mac world is either the same or has a very close equivalent, but the PC route is to R-Click a running flash app > global settings > security manager > and add your workspace to the trusted space.

This might get you there a little quicker:
http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

If it's working on an equivalent cpu from your friend, what player version are you running vs. what he/she is running?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is AIR/Android mobile app. There is no right click or such settings like with flash. Also, we're running the app on the same phone...Just exporting it from FLash builder to the Android device, and when published from my computer...its a black screen...force quit. When exporting it from his computer....works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Tested it on multiple devices to see if it was just my phone

What was the outcome of this?

Have you ensured you have the correct [USB Drivers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa8161994b114d624-33657d5912b7ab2d73b-7fdf.html#WSa8161994b114d624-33657d5912b7ab2d73b-7fdc) installed to remotely debug on the android device?

Comment: Mountain Lion is OS X, not Windows, so there are no USB Drivers to install.

Comment: Solved the problem... It turns out that we didn't have the Paid Application Contract signed in the itunes connect.. All of our apps are free, so we didn't think we needed to sign that. But you need to in order to have in app purchases. You can't even test them unless you have that signed! Wish they would've told us that during the process of creating our account.